# Downloads number of app stuck

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app on the google play market, and it shows it has 50+ downloads while in my developer console I can see more than 500 downloads.
Almost 2 weeks passed since I reached 500.
What I miss?
This is the app page if necessary:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=zachinio.travelalbum

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw other questions about google play asked here and thought it's relevant.

Comment: Yeah but this is clearly about the app store policy. So it deserves to be asked to customer support .

Answer (score 1):

This happens everytime when you cross a Download Number threshold...
for e.g. 10, 50, 100, 500, 1K, 5K,  10K, 50K, 100K & so On...
When your App crosses any of the above or other, it takes Google some good amount of time to Update the Install Count all over the "World"...
It takes time...
Wait for few more days, if it still doesn't change then contact Play Support :)

Comment: It just weird because when my other apps crossed the 100 downloads Google updated it with few days and now i have been waiting for weeks,but I'll wait another week, thank you mate.